# How to enable ASLR in a Windows PE binary?

Tags: aslr

How do i enable Address Space Layout Randomization of an executable?

**Note**: i am not using Visual Studio, or any compiler that provides a `/dynamicbase` compiler option.

For the purposes of this discussion, assume i am adding functionality to a compiler to enable ASLR.

## Other PE Flags

There are other Windows executable image options that i already know how to set. For example, then `IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP` flag. You set the PE option in the PE binary header:

```
LOADED_IMAGE li;
MapAndLoad(fileName), null, li, false, false)

LI.FileHeader.FileHeader.Characteristics |= IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP;

UnMapAndLoad(li)
```

How does one enable **Address Space Layout Randomization**? Is it a PE flags? Is it an **Assembly Manifest** entry?

## Bonus

How do i opt an executable into NX (No Execute)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is that the option *is* embedded in the PE binary header. But rather than

```
loadedImage.FileHeader.FileHeader.Characteristics
```

it's in:

```
loadedImage.FileHeader.OptionalHeader.DllCharacteristics
```

Where you set the flag:

```
IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE = 0x0040; //The DLL can be relocated at load time.
```

For a helper function pseudo-code of:

```
void SetPEOptFlags(String filename, UInt32 flags)
{
   // Any code is released into the public domain. No attribution required.
   LOADED_IMAGE li;
   MapAndLoad(filename, null, li, false, false);
  
   li.FileHeader.OptionalHeader.DllCharacteristics |= flags;
   UnMapAndLoad(li);
}
```

and then calling

```
//Optional dll characteristics
const IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE = 0x0040; //The DLL can be relocated at load time.
const IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NX_COMPAT =    0x0100; //The image is compatible with data execution prevention (DEP).


SetPEOptFlags("C:\Foo\Contoso.exe", 
   IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_DYNAMIC_BASE | IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NX_COMPAT);
```